# Users logged in but can't see them

Tags: command-line

I am just starting with linux commands, so my question might sound incredibly stupid.
I am studying the command line, yesterday I was creating and deleting users.

When trying to delete a user (bart) I had created with the command

```
deluser bart
```

it says that bart is still logged in.
I thought that the command `w` shows people logged in. So I tried it, and it did not mention bart. However, when trying to delete bart again I would get the same reply.

Is that normal? Am I using the wrong command to see who is logged in?

---

I did that and I logged out bart. However, I still don't understand why I can't find a command that lists all users logged in.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to kill the user bart's processes and kick him off the session. I would try this: `# pkill -STOP -u bart`

Though I do apologise as I have not yet tried this command myself. I found it from this great source: [Link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-kill-and-logout-users.html)

I hope this helps you.